# How to copy a file from one gcp instance to another gcp instance in same project

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, scp

I am currently running 29 instances in each available regions on GCP. And I need all of the instances to have some python script file.

As I was getting tired to upload them manually through the console 29 times, I was wondering if there's a way to upload the script in only one instance, and copy them all over to 28 other instances with gcloud scp command?

Currently, I was trying the following:

```
sudo gcloud compute scp --zone='asia-east1-b' /home/file.txt instance-asia-east1:/home/
```

The code above is trying to scp "file.txt" over to the instance-asia-east1.
I included the sudo command as it was having some permission issues. But after adding the sudo, I get another error message:

```
root@000.000.000.00: Permission denied (publickey).
lost connection
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.scp) [/usr/bin/scp] exited with return code [1].
```

What can be the issue, and how can I resolve this?

Comment: Try to SSH first, which should set up the SSH keys.

Comment: @john-hanley that was going to be my answer too ;-) But, I think `gcloud compute scp` will propagate keys (assuming `google_compute_engine` exists locally?). I think the issue is that `sudo`'ing `gcloud` causes it to look from `/root` for `gcloud` credentials and SSH keys.

Comment: @DazWilkin - good eyes. I missed **sudo**, which changes the user context.

Comment: The first solution I got from my head is that put the file in GCS?

Answer (score 3):

You should avoid using `sudo`.

If you add `--verbosity=debug` to (any but in this case) `gcloud compute ssh` or `gcloud compute scp` command, you'll see that `gcloud` invokes your host's (probably `/usr/bin`) `ssh` and `scp` commands. It uses a private key that was generated by `gcloud` using your credentials (`gcloud config get account` or the default `gcloud auth list`).

```sh
gcloud compute scp \
  ${PWD}/${FILE} \
  ${INSTANCE}:. \
  --project=${PROJECT} \
  --zone=${ZONE} \
  --verbosity=debug
```

Yielding:

```
DEBUG: Running [gcloud.compute.scp] with arguments: ...
...
DEBUG: Current SSH keys in project: ['...:ssh-rsa ... user@host']
DEBUG: Running command [/usr/bin/scp -i .../.ssh/google_compute_engine -o ...
INFO: Display format: "default"
DEBUG: SDK update checks are disabled.
```

> **NOTE** `/usr/bin/scp -i .../.ssh/google_compute_engine ...`

When you run as `sudo`, even if you copy your credentialed user's `google_compute_engine` SSH keys (to e.g. `/root/.ssh`), the authenticated user won't match, unless you also duplicate the `gcloud` config...

I recommend you solve the permission issue that triggered your use of `sudo`.